# Replace text selection event with dragstart, move, dragend OR other mouse movement events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

A client of ours needs to be able to use touch-enabled Surface tablets to access our intranet application, via a browser accessed over Remote Desktop.  Unfortunately, the OS they're remoting into is Windows 2008 Server R2, which has no meaningful touch support built in.  When you touch the screen, your finger seems to act exactly like a left-click-and-pointer-move, which results in text being selected on the browser, instead of doing the drag/scroll action that most people expect (and which works perfectly with every other "touch client" combination we've used to access our system).  As a result, their only way of scrolling the screen is with the scrollbars, which feels unintuitive on a touch device.

1. Is there a way to handle events in such a way as to convert this text selection event (or series of events) to other mouse events?  I'm thinking we'd start by `e.preventDefault`, but I don't know where I'd go from there.  We don't need to support all default touch events; all we really need is vertical scrolling.
2. Does any other solution come to mind, for allowing the "pointer" to drag the document body?

Answer (score 0):

A mixture or either of two things can be tried:

a) Set `pointer-events: none` on the text blocks to let them ignore mouse events (and effectively pass them through to what's behind).

b) Set `user-select: none` to disable text selection.